# How to submit data using knockout.. and I have below form like this

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

How to submit data using knockout in mvc4
and  I have created a form with employee id, employee name, designation and department is selected based in drop down that code is already working fine but I was strucked while while submiting only .

but how should i get textbox values to viewmodel and bind it to data property?

```
<div id="div1">
    <table align="center"> 
        <tr>
            <td>enter code here
                Employee Id:
            </td>
            <td>enter code here
                <input data-bind="value:EmpId" type="text" id="txtempid"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name:
            </td>
            <td><input data-bind="value:EmpName" type="text" id="txtempname"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Designation:
            </td>
            <td><input data-bind="value:Designation" type="text" id="txtdesignation"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                 Department Name:
            </td>
            <td> 
                <select id="CategoryType" style="width: 250px; height: 25px; margin-top:10px;" data-bind="optionsText:'deptname', value:deptid"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" />
                    &nbsp
                    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And I tried like below using knockout  but getting  an error..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnSave').live("click", function (e) {
        var viewModel = {
         this.EmpId: ko.observable(""),
         this.EmpName: ko.observable(""),
         this.Designation: ko.observable(""), 
         this.deptid:ko.observable("")
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Save/',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            data: ko.toJSON(viewmodel),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
            $("lblResult").val("Recorded inserted Sucessfully");
                $("txtempid").text("");
                $("txtdeptid").text("");
                $("txtempname").text("");
                $("txtdesignation").text("");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can any one suggest answer please   ........  for submitting this data to controller and then I will save it to database.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: So where is the 'data-bind' attribute? Put complete error message on question too.

Comment: i got only  that error .....

Comment: Also put the header of the Controllers method code in the question. Make sure you don´t have this annotation `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

Comment: it works but you have to remove "this." elements on the ViewModel part

Comment: on self.click event get model then`var data = ko.toJS(model);` and then `$.post("/Create", data)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ViewModel.js:

```
var viewModel = function () {
var self = this;

self.EmpId = ko.observable("");
self.EmpName = ko.observable("");
self.Designation = ko.observable("");
self.DeptId = ko.observable("1")

self.Message = ko.observable("")
self.DeptIds = ko.observableArray([]);

self.getDeptIds = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/GetDeptIds/',
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            self.DeptIds(data);             
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.status != 403)
                alert("Status: " + xhr.status + ", Error: " + thrownError, "Error");
        }
    });

};
self.getDeptIds();

self.Update = function () {     
    var Employee = {};
    Employee.EmpId = self.EmpId();
    Employee.EmpName = self.EmpName();
    Employee.Designation = self.Designation();
    Employee.DeptId = self.DeptId();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Save/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: Employee,
        success: function (result) {                
            self.Message("Recorded inserted Sucessfully");

            self.EmpId("");
            self.EmpName("");
            self.Designation("");
            self.DeptId("")
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            debugger;
            alert("some error");
        }
    });
};
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            enter code here
            Employee Id:
        </td>
        <td>
            enter code here
            <input data-bind="value:EmpId" type="text" id="txtempid" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value:EmpName" type="text" id="txtempname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Designation:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value:Designation" type="text" id="txtdesignation" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Department Name:
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="CategoryType" style="width: 250px; height: 25px; margin-top:
    10px;" data-bind="options: DeptIds, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value', value: DeptId"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" data-bind="click: Update" />
            &nbsp
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" />
        </td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <div id="lblResult" data-bind="text: Message"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
@section scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
     });
  </script>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult Save(Employee Employee)
{
    //**DOTO**//
    //Save the Data

    return Json(Employee, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public JsonResult GetDeptIds()
{
    List<Dept> depts = new List<Dept>();
    depts.Add(new Dept { name = "debt 1", value = "1" });
    depts.Add(new Dept { name = "debt 2", value = "2" });
    depts.Add(new Dept { name = "debt 3", value = "3" });
    depts.Add(new Dept { name = "debt 4", value = "4" });
    return Json(depts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string DeptId { get; set; }
}

public class Dept
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; } 
}
```

please note:
the main idea working with `knockoutjs` is MVVM that mean to leave all java script code out of the html page

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. but above code is not working... because i am getting dropdown values from database and you statically define . so i was not understand

Comment: you are wellcom, i changed the code so it's like getting the dropdown from the DB

Comment: another change i did is sending the Employee object from the javascript as is (wo parsing to Json) that way i got the object in the Save function correctly

Answer (score 1):

Knockout + SharePoint = Shockout SP Forms

I wrote a comprehensive framework that combines the power of Knockout JS data binding with SharePoint REST services for truly modern and dynamic SharePoint forms without the headache of InfoPath or XSLT. The framework is called "Shockout" and you can download it here https://github.com/jbonfardeci/ShockoutForms.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems related to a javascript syntax error, not to knockout nor to the AJAX call.

One issue is the following part of your code:

```
var viewModel = {
    this.EmpId: ko.observable(""),
    this.EmpName: ko.observable(""),
    this.Designation: ko.observable(""), 
    this.deptid:ko.observable("")
};
```

You shouldn't prefix your property names with `this.`. It should probably look similar to the following:

```
var viewModel = {
    EmpId: ko.observable(""),
    EmpName: ko.observable(""),
    Designation: ko.observable(""), 
    deptid:ko.observable("")
};
```

I don't know if this is the only issue, but it's one at least.

Edit: Adding a mention of case sensitivity issues

JavaScript is also a case sensitive language. You initially declare your `viewModel` with a capital `M` and you later try to use it without any capital letters, i.e. `viewmodel`.

This causes your `ko.applyBinding` call to bind to an undefined reference and thus none of the properties you're trying to bind to exist. Make sure you're consistent in your casing.

Comment: thanks for reply ok. but how should i get textbox values to viewmodel and bind it to data property

Comment: I've updated the code to show why you're currently not binding to your `viewModel` object. Also, be aware that you're actually performing your AJAX call immediately after the call to `ko.applyBindings`, so it will be called before you have any time to make any changes to your `viewModel` object.

Comment: I have copied your code above into a jsfiddle and made the changes I've mentioned above (and also changed from `live` to `on` since I used jQuery 2.1 and [`live` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/)). This seems to work just fine, as you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/pL7RL/. However, since you have placed the creation of the `viewModel` and the call to `ko.applyBindings` in the click event of the save button, these are not bound until you click that button. You shouldn't use jQuery to bind the click event, instead use the knockout `click` binding on the button.